# jewish in secret or martyrdom?

Tags: halacha, islam, martyr

If I live in a extreme Islamic country that would most likely kill me for being jewish and moving is not an option, is it unacceptable for me to practice in secret? or should I confess my faith and be a martyr?

Comment: I believe Rambam wrote in a letter that it was preferable for a Jew to accept Islamic principles rather than die because Islam itself is not avodah zarah. I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: @rosenjcb, I will really appreciate it thank you brother

Comment: @eliyah It's already been answered:

possible duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28390/conversion-to-islam